# Calculate Field Dynamically With Search Condition in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sum, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to make a dynamic sum of a field, for example on ex1.jpg:

[ex1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1upr.jpg)

When I use search with a condition, the total list is 21 data then I just want to sum 21 data at the bottom of the list view just displayed sum of 20 data (showed data).

But on the bottom left of list view sum all of data (more than 21 data), on ex2.jpg:

[ex2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knAvw.jpg)

I searched using a different condition but still displays sum of all data.

Can anyone help my problem?

Comment: Use javascript/ jquery to sum in dynamically.

Comment: Hi kimbarcelona, any suggestion for it? maybe useful link to do that on suitecrm?

Comment: I am done in my custom module to add total amount at bottom of listview. 1) need to customized view.list.php 2) create custom tpl form sum 3) add custom tpl to end of list tpl 4) in list view function listViewProcess customized to calculate total amount and assing in smarty variable 5) use this variable in sum tpl.

Comment: In listview process this code use to calculate total.  $total = 0; 
            foreach($this->lv->data['data'] as $entry) { 
    $total += unformat_number($entry['AMOUNT_USDOLLAR']);

Comment: i think we not need to use js and jquery for this

Answer (score 0):

I am done in my custom module to add total amount at bottom of listview.

1. Need to customized view.list.php
2. Create custom tpl form sum
3. add custom tpl to end of list tpl
4. in list view function listViewProcess customized to calculate total amount     and assing in smarty variable
5. use this variable in sum tpl

In listview process this code use to calculate total.

```
$total = 0; 
foreach($this->lv->data['data'] as $entry) { 
   $total += unformat_number($entry['AMOUNT_USDOLLAR']);
}
```